# GeoServer workspace store change via REST API

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

Currently the way we have to change the GeoServer workspace of store is:

1. GET call for old_workspace and store
2. POST Call for new_workspace with updated body of 1. by replacing all old_workspace names with new_workspace
3. GET call for old_workspace, store and layer
4. POST call with new_workspace, store and updated body of 3.

Is there any easier way to change the workspace of store via REST API?